# ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py37_0'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I'm trying to install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator on windows10 for python3.7 using conda.
An error occurred while installing the package.

I have already tried to reinstall anaconda,but the problem still occurs.

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py37_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py37_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Cesare\Anaconda3\Scripts\.jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-post-link.bat
```

I want to know how to install it successfully.

Comment: Can you verify that there is Jupyter binary at `C:\Users\Cesare\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe`? You may need to also install the Conda Forge `jupyter_core` package. Sometimes Anaconda and Conda Forge packages are incompatible.

Comment: any update on this. I am the same error message when trying to update Conda `conda update --force conda
`

Answer (score 2):

I too was facing the same problem. Here's the output when I tried cloning the base environment [*Running as Administrator*]:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  conda create --name django --clone base
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at 'C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3\envs\django'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? y

Source:      C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3
Destination: C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3\envs\django
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - conda-forge/win-64::conda-4.9.2-py38haa244fe_0
 - defaults/win-64::conda-build-3.20.5-py38_1
 - defaults/win-64::conda-env-2.6.0-1
Packages: 305
Files: 2077
Preparing transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(698): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0\Library\bin\openssl.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
()
```

You will notice the package giving me problem is different than yours, but the ERROR remains the same (**ERROR conda.core.link**).

---

### Here's how I solved it:

1. Google the package mentioned in the ERROR. In my case it was *openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0*
2. Open the result from Anaconda Files (should likely be the first search result):
   **anaconda / packages / openssl 1 - Files :: Anaconda Cloud**
3. Ctrl+F to find the package in the list.
4. Download the compressed package to your local Downloads folder.
5. Backup the contents of the installed erroneous package **C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0** somewhere.
6. Copy the contents of the de-compressed downloaded package into the **C:\Users\Tanishk\anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1h-he774522_0** folder.
7. Re-try in Anaconda prompt with whatever you got stuck at.

Note:

- After step 7, I got another same error but for a different package this time (vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_3). I performed the same steps for this package too --> Google -- Download -- Replace old content. And I was able to run things successfully after that.
- I suggest to google the package because if you search for the package name on Anaconda itself, it will ask you to login first.